# Rotational motion in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

From analysis of translational motion and transformation of reference frame, one conclude the upper limit of velocity cannot exceed the speed of light. In classical mechanics, the velocity by rotation is given by $\vec{v}=\vec{r}x\vec{\omega}$. Consider the case of infinite long rod, then a seemingly paradox that to prevent violating upper limit of velocity, on cannot rotate the rod as the velocity by rotation will easily exceed the limit. Can anyone give an account on relativistic correction on rotation? Namely, such as the derivation and consequence of Thomas precession?

Comment: Thomas precession has nothing to do with the rest of the question. You should delete the last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The "paradox" is resolved because you cannot get a real rod to rigidly rotate at the relativistic speeds that you're considering.  Imagine that you had a really long rod at rest with one end of the rod at the origin of your coordinate system.  Now you want to start rotating the rod around the origin, hoping to make the far end travel with a speed greater than light.  As you begin applying force at the origin to try to make this happen, you encounter at least two issues:

1. The "information" that you've started applying torque on your end can only travel down the rod (at most) at the speed of light.  So you cannot create truly rigid rotation on a real rod.  It will have to either bend or break since your end starts moving before the far end does.
2. To whatever extent you did get the rod rotating, you have to put energy into the system to take it from rest to "large" angular speed.  If your rod hasn't broken yet, you still face the reality that the mass at the far end of the rod needs more and more energy to get closer to moving at the speed of light - in the limit, it needs infinite energy.  So even if your rod somehow hasn't snapped, you can never put enough energy into the system to get any part of the rod to (or past) the speed of light.

I don't see where Thomas precession is relevant to the original question.